# python how tu get Coordinated Universal Time universal coordinate time?

Tags: python, time, utc

i'm able to get UTC time that's the actually time.
using:

```
datetime.now
```

I need to get the univeral utc not local here is the clock: https://time.is/es/UTC

Answer (score 0):

You should practically always use `.now()` with the UTC timezone

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Refer to the [comment on `.utcnow()` in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow)

This takes from the system clock, so you'll need to make sure NTP is configured on your system

Comment: Hi !  what i need is the universal coordinate time which now is 3:52 you can check it here https://time.is/es/UTC